# use wildcard with Terms in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I wanted to simulate SQL's IN so I used terms filter, but terms does not support wild cards like adding astrisck in "*egypt*".

so how can i achieve the following query?

PS: i am using [elastica](http://elastica.io/)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "country_name": [
              "*egypt*",
              "*italy*"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "rank": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473653/elastic-query-dsl-wildcards-in-terms-filter

Comment: thanks, but the problem here with terms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`terms` query does not support wildcards. You can use `match` or `wildcard` query instead. If your problem is multiple values to filter you can combine queries inside `should`, so it will look like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "country_name": "*egypt*"
          }
        },
        {
            "wildcard": {
                "country_name": "*italy*"
            }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "rank": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```